# grails spring security oauth still requires a local username/password?

Tags: grails, oauth, spring-security

I am using grails/spring security/oauth plugins. However, when using an oauth provider the system still requires the user to create a username and password in system to complete the registration process. Is there any way to make the username/password not required if the user is using an oauth provider? Maybe by making the email address the username (another thing I would like to do but can not find an easy solution)?

Thanks

Comment: I am hitting the same issue.  I was wondering what you did to resolve this?  My own thoughts were to just override how the spring security oauth plugin was handling user registration and write my own registration controller/page that would not require a password as long as the user came in via the OAuth path.

Answer (score -1):

You need to bind the 3rd party authentication somewhere to your local security setup. This is what the SecUser class is for (see: [spring-security-core](http://blog.springsource.com/2010/08/11/simplified-spring-security-with-grails/) plugin). You can generate this class and modify it to suit your needs. The OAuth bit I don't know much about but I assume there are some callback points where you can add the behaviour you want. (OAuth ID Class perhaps?)